# How do you specify infinity in StackExchange.Redis?

Tags: c#, stackexchange.redis

Redis allows you to specify positive or negative infinity as range arguments, such as in the following example from [ZCOUNT](http://redis.io/commands/zcount):

> ZCOUNT myzset -inf +inf

How do you specify these values in StackExchange.Redis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The score is a `double`, so:

```
var count = conn.SortedSetLength("myzset",
    double.NegativeInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity);
```

In fact, since those are the defaults:

```
var count = conn.SortedSetLength("myzset");
```